# Pipeline not being triggered on pull-request (github-pullrequest-builder)

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, pull-request, jenkins-github-plugin

I have some problems with getting GitHub Pull Request Builder to work.
While configuring this plugin I used all of the given tests to check:

- basic connection to GitHub
- permissions to a repository
- adding comment to pull-request
- updating commit status

All of these things work right, but issuing pullrequest does not trigger the pipeline start. All I was able to get out of Jenkins logs is just an info that pr is being checked...[jenkins_logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJf8O.png)

Have anyone run into the same trouble? I can't find a solution to this problem.